# What joints of Apollo 17 space suits did moon dust get into, making the astronauts arms difficult to move?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, spacesuits, space-dust

At about `02:45` the Curious Droid video [Apollo, the Lunar Dust and NASA's Dirty Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFqpgmZAZgo) says:

> During Apollo 17, crew members Harrison “Jack” Schmitt and Gene Cernan had reported that the dust was making it difficult fro them to move their arms around, because it had got into the joint of their spacesuits.

What suit joints is he talking about? All I see exposed is fabric.

[image: Curious Droid Apollo, the Lunar Dust and NASA's Dirty Problem]

Cued at `02:45`:

Comment: There's a long discussion of the adverse effects of the dust here https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/AS17Tech6.pdf but the EVA crew never say anything about it affecting their suits. They talk about the bad effects on the rover, on breathing it in, etc, etc, but nary a word about suit joints. Hard to prove a negative but...

Comment: @OrganicMarble it didn't sound right to me, that's why I posted. If you continue to feel the same way after further deliberation (i.e. just wait 24 hours and pretend you deliberates) then feel free to post a answer to the negative.

Comment: I'm not going to suffer through watching the youtube video so it doesn't seem fair for me to post an answer criticizing it.  I'll limit myself to a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no joints to be seen within the arms assembley, only fabric.

[image]

But at the lower end of the arm there is the wrist ring.

[image]

This ring is used for a gas tight connection of the gloves to the suit. But there must be another function of this wrist ring, it should allow the rotation of the hands.
I remember a video of the suiting procedure of an Apollo astronaut, he tested carefully the rotation of his hands, the movement was smooth and easy.

But if this wrist ring and its counter part in the gloves are contaminated with moon dust, rotation of the hands may be impaired. Between these two metal rings there must be a O-ring seal and some of the lubrication of these O-rings might been lost due to the vacuum during EVA. The remaining lubrication may have mixed with moon dust making rotation difficult.

All images from a NASA page about [Buzz Aldrin's Apollo 11 Suit](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/A11BA-Flown-Suit.html)

In this [report](https://history.nasa.gov/spacesuits.pdf) about space suits evolution rotary bearings are mentioned in the section about Space Shuttle suits on page 13:

> The  gloves incorporate a rotary bearing to allow wrist rotation,

In the section about the Apollo suits on page 7:

> An  example  of  this  stiffness:  inflate  a  large cylindrical 
>   balloon  or  the  inner  tube  of  a  tire, the  balloon  or  tube 
>   will  become  very  stilt  and almost impossible  to  twist  or  bend.
>   Without these  specially  developed  joints  for  the  space suit,  It 
>   would  be  virtually  impossible  for  the astronaut  to  do  useful 
>   work  on  the  moon's surface.  These  special  joints  are  installed 
>   Into the   CMP   A7LB   suit at the knees, wrist, shoulders,
>   elbows, ankles, and thighs.

From this PDF [APOLLO OPERATIONS HANDBOOK EXTRAVEHICULAR MOBILITY UNIT](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-EMU1.pdf) on page 2-23:

> The glove side-wrist disconnect is the male portion of the wrist
>   disconnect assembly and features a sealed bearing which permits 360°
>   glove rotation.

[image]

Figure 2-15 from page 2-44.

Lubricants were used for O-rings (page 2-78):

> The lubricant pouch assembly contains eight fluorinated, oil­
>   saturated pads which are used to lubricate pressure sealing slide
>   fasteners, seals, and "O" rings. The pads are held in place in  the
>   center  pouch of  the  pocket assembly by whip­stitched Beta thread.

**So a rotary joint is located in the wrist disconnect at the glove side.**

Comment: this is getting pretty interesting!

Comment: There are good pictures of the arm bellows joints in the pressure garment at this anti-moon-hoaxer page: http://www.moonhoaxdebunked.com/2017/07/815-how-come-pressurized-spacesuits.html  There was a rotary bearing at the shoulder but only a bellows joint at the elbow.